# Using lstrip on path strips too much from path

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, path

I'm having a weird issue with lstrip, with the following setup I get:

```
In[42]: file_path
Out[42]: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Company\\MATLAB\\V_Common\\v_matlab\\V_Scripts\\Yaw\\getYaw.m'

In[43]: folder_path
Out[43]: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Company\\MATLAB\\V_Common\\v_matlab'

In[44]: file_path.lstrip(folder_path)
Out[44]: 'Scripts\\Yaw\\getYaw.m'
```

Why is the 'V_' part disapearing? Doing this to a example path doesn't give the same result.

```
In[45]: 'C:\\a\\b\\V_\\e\\f'.lstrip('C:\\a\\b')
Out[45]: 'V_\\e\\f'

In[46]: file_path.startswith(folder_path)
Out[46]: True

In[47]: file_path[len(folder_path)+1:]
Out[47]: 'V_Scripts\\Yaw\\getYaw.m'
```

Is there some special functionality in lstrip that I'm missing?

Comment: yes, it works char by char, not what you want. You want `replace`

Comment: Damn, all this time... Guess I have some old code to revisit.